# error with python socket module, client closing immediately on startup

Tags: python, sockets

the issue with my program is as follows:
i've been working on a socket server for some rp stuff dont mind that part, the more worrisome part is the fact that now my client just closes after trying to fix a massive vulnerability where if you press enter it will show "invalid input" then press enter again it will just log you into the server itself via a prompt shown after login. that part isnt relevant only the fact that the client closes immediately when i open it, any advice or issues i should look at? you should also note that `def passwd():` was added in attempt to fix the issue, what i did was put the password prompt in a function, then call the function after connecting via ngrok tunnel, the code is below:

```
import socket
from os import name as os_name, system
from colorama import init, Fore as cc
import select
import time
dr = DR = r = R = cc.LIGHTRED_EX
g = G = cc.LIGHTGREEN_EX
b = B = cc.LIGHTBLUE_EX
m = M = cc.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX
c = C = cc.LIGHTCYAN_EX
y = Y = cc.LIGHTYELLOW_EX
w = W = cc.RESET
HEADER = 64
clear = lambda: system('cls') if os_name == 'nt' else system('clear')
clear()
PORT = input("Enter Port Number > ")
FORMAT = "utf-8"
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!disconnect"
SERVER = input("Enter Tunnel Address > ")
PORT1 = int(PORT)
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT1)
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)
passwd()

def send(msg):
    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))
clear()
def ssrselec():
    ssr = input("Input User ID > ")
    if ssr:
        clear()
        send(ssr)
        time.sleep(2)
    if not ssr:
        clear()
        print("INVALID INPUT")
        client.close()

def select():
    selec = input("Types: Internal, External\n\nSelect Database Type > ")
    if selec:
        clear()
        send(selec)
        time.sleep(2)
        ssrselec()
    if not selec:
        clear()
        print("INVALID INPUT")
        client.close()

print("To disconnect type !disconnect\n")
def passwd():
    inp = input("Input Database Password > ")
    if inp:
        clear()
        send(inp)
        time.sleep(2)
        select()
    if not inp:
        clear()
        print("INVALID INPUT")
        client.close()
inp2 = input(" > ")
if inp2:
    clear()
    send(inp2)
    time.sleep(2)
    select()
if not inp2:
    clear()
    print("INVALID INPUT")
    client.close()
clear()
select()
clear()
```

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see if code works as you expect.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could use `else:` instead of `if not selec:` , `if not ssr:` , `if not inp:` , `if not inp2:`

Answer (score 0):

my linter shows that `passwd()` is called before it is declared.

You should define `passwd()` before it is called.

You can do this by defining it earlier in the code or by hoisting all functions with this at the end:

```
if __name__==`__main__`:
    # some code
```